# Multiplying an array with data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` named `dt` that looks as follows:

```
 ID V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 time color
 1  F  T  F  F  T  1    red
 1  F  T  T  F  T  2    red
 2  T  F  T  F  F  1    blue
 3  F  F  F  F  F  2    green
 3  T  T  T  F  T  3    purple
```

In reality, `dim(dt) = [1321221 123]`. Now I know that in general, true and false are stored as 1 and 0, respectively, in R. I also have an array `l`, though that looks like

```
 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
 1  2  1  3  4
```

These are weights assigned to `V1,V2,V3,V4,V5`. I would like to multiply these weights to the true values (as they have a numeric value of 1) and add across each row, like we can do with matrices. The output should look like

```
ID Total time color
1  6     1    red
1  7     2    red
2  2     1    blue
3  0     2    green
3  8     3    purple
```

Now remember, this is actually a tiny subset of the real data, so I am looking for a fast solution, and preferably a `data.table` solution so I can improve on my `data.table` skills.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dt[, .(ID, Reduce(`+`, Map(`*`, .SD, l)), time, color), .SDcols = V1:V5]
#   ID V2 time  color
#1:  1  6    1    red
#2:  1  7    2    red
#3:  2  2    1   blue
#4:  3  0    2  green
#5:  3  8    3 purple

# or using matrix product

dt[, .(ID, as.matrix(.SD) %*% t(l), time, color), .SDcols = V1:V5]
```

Comment: This may require version 1.9.7+. I don't remember when the columns outside of `.SDcols` bug was fixed, but I think it was fairly recently.

Answer (score 1):

@Eddi has a cleaner answer, but if you need something in version 1.9.6:

```
dt[, Total := apply((t(l * t(dt[, 2:6, with = FALSE]))),1,sum)]
dt[, 2:6 := NULL]
setcolorder(dt, c("ID", "Total", "time", "color"))
```